# Conditional logic in compile or link function of angular js directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a JSON object in `$scope` called `data`. The object has a member called `items` which may either be an Object or Array of Objects. For this reason I  can't use ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.items">
        <item data="item"></item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...because if `data.items` is an object it creates an `<item>` directive for each **member** in `data.items`. However things work fine if `data.items` is an array. I thought I could do something like:

```
<span ng-if="angular.isObject(data.items)">
    <span ng-if="angular.isDefined(data.items)">
          <item data="data.item"></item>
    </span>
</span>
```

But this doesn't work, I guess because I need the argument to isObject and isDefined to be an expression that can be resolved, but wrapping the argument in `{{}}}` just results in a syntax error.

I then thought I could create a directive that would inspect items and modify the template element in the compile function, however this requires access to data on $scope, which compile functions don't have. I think the linking function would be too late to modify the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```html
<ul ng-if="data.items.length>0">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.items">
        <item data="item"></item>
    </li>
</ul>

<span ng-if="data.items && !(data.items.length>0)">
  <item data="data.items"></item>
</span>
```

Comment: I had to add `<span ng-if="(data.items != null)">` around this, but it worked.

Comment: Ok, I've made an update that should work if data.items is undefined as well